# PDO SQL Delete statement not found

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm having trouble with an SQL statement I'm trying to execute through PDO. No exceptions are throw only a warning :"sh: 1: DELETE: not found". I'm not sure if the error lies in my syntax or the installation/setup of pdo any help?

```
try {
    $ConnectionObj = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Person", 'user', '1234');
    $ConnectionObj->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $SqlStr = "DELETE FROM Details WHERE EmailAddress = '".$EmailAddrStr."' ";
    exec($SqlStr);
    //echo "Person deleted"."\n";
}
catch (PDOException $exception) {
    echo $exception;
}
```

Comment: `exec` isn't a pdo function..

Comment: @treyBake is right **exec()** will execute the shell command and due to that only you are facing **sh: 1: DELETE: not found** warning as shell is trying to find **Delete** command.

Comment: And you will have to `print_r($exception)` or `var_dump($exception)` as `$exception` is not a scalar value so `echo` will generate its own error

Answer (score 4):

`exec()` isn't a PDO function, it's used to run external applications:

```
exec

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

exec — Execute an external program
Description 
exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] ) : string

exec() executes the given command.
```

Instead, do something like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'usr', 'pass');

$sql = "DELETE FROM Details WHERE EmailAddress = :addr";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':addr' => $EmailAddrStr]);
```

more info can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

Comment: exec() isn't a PDO function, though there is `PDO::exec()` function

Comment: @OTAR that's a good point actually, I imagine that's where the initial confusion lies! will

Comment: I would also recommend to add the charset and enable error reporting when you are creating instance of PDO.